# How do I store & access a Twitter Fabric login session (iOS/Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm able to log in to Twitter through my app using this Twitter Fabric code:

```
 let logInButton = TWTRLogInButton(logInCompletion: {
        (session: TWTRSession!, error: NSError!) in
             // play with Twitter session
             if (session != nil) {
                 println("signed in as \(session.userName)");
                 self.TWUsernameLabel.text = "Logged in as @" + session.userName
        } else {
            println("error: \(error.localizedDescription)");
        }
    })
```

When I click the login button, it prompts me to approve the login and then logs me in, or it knows I already approved the login and it logs me in. This works like a charm and took all of ten minutes to set up. Amazing.

I already have an email-based login to access the app. I'd like to store a user's logged in Twitter account in that same database, so when a user logs in with their email, I already know their Twitter (if they have logged in before) and they don't need to log in again. The reason I do the email login is because Twitter is an important feature in my app, but not a total requirement.

The issue is that I have no idea how to access `session` outside of when the button is clicked and `logInCompletion` fires, and I don't know what variables to store upon initial login/check upon using the app.

I've read through the Twitter Fabric documentation numerous times, but it isn't written in swift, so it's pretty confusing. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is currently an active session you should be able to access it just like the docs say to

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().session()
```

If the user isn't logged in that method will return nil. If you want to know if someone is already authenticated just check to see if that method returns a value or not.

Comment: Well that was simple. Thanks! But before I check this as the solution, is there any point in storing some sort of Twitter information in my user database? I'm going to store the username just in case, but I'm talking about from a session/login perspective. Should I store a key or anything? (I'm thinking about how you store a session id and then check it against what gets stored on a computer.) It's possible this system is specifically designed to avoid that. I'm not sure. Thoughts?

Comment: No I wouldn't store it. Twitter is already doing that for us and I am certain that they handle this more sanely than you or I could with our own implementation. If a session exists, they're logged into Twitter. If it doesn't they aren't. You ought to take their API for its word on that.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually the correct answer is Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session() since you can have more than one Twitter account per device and per app.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to cast the returned object to `TWTRSession` to get at the username. Seems odd.

Comment: can you please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074159/fabric-twittersession-always-null ?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter kit automatically present a login screen if user has not logged in (no session exist..).
But, before calling any future API, just check whether session is valid or not. In some APIs, you may required to pass this session too.

```
if ([[Twitter sharedInstance] session]) {

        TWTRShareEmailViewController *shareEmailViewController =
        [[TWTRShareEmailViewController alloc]
         initWithCompletion:^(NSString *email, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Email %@ | Error: %@", email, error);
         }];

        [self presentViewController:shareEmailViewController
                           animated:YES
                         completion:nil];
    } else {
        // Handle user not signed in (e.g. attempt to log in or show an alert)
    }
}
```

You even don't need to worry about storing and managing `access token` and `access token secret`.

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to get the Twitter session using this code [[Twitter sharedInstance] session]. I installed the Twitter kit with pod:   pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'TwitterKit'. But when I run the build failed: "Use of undeclared identifier Twitter". This is how I imported it #import <Twitter/Twitter.h>. Can you help me please?

Comment: Have you written : `#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>` ?

Comment: No. Have I to add it?

Comment: Yes...
  `#import <Fabric/Fabric.h> #import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h> #import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>`

Comment: Without #import <Twitter/Twitter.h>?

Comment: No...also `<TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>`

Comment: It gives me 'Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h' file not found. and the same for Fabric/Fabric.h.

Comment: Can you check it here please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137640/fabric-check-session

Answer (score 0):

To access the authToken, userName or the userID for the logged in user session in Swift 4 is:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logIn(completion: { (session, error) in
     if (session != nil) {
         print(session!.authToken)
         print(session!.userName)
         print(session!.userID)
     } else {
         print(error?.localizedDescription)
     }
})
```