# How can I store and reuse a TwitterSession on Android?

Tags: android, twitter, sdk

I'm trying to build a simple Twitter widget app for Android, not doing much more than just displaying certain tweets. I have an `Activity` with a Twitter log in button which successfully returns me a `TwitterSession` object.

Now how can I store my credentials and use it even after a phone reboot? I have:

```
m_loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
        // Store the result which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
        TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
        TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
        prefs.putString("net.example.authToken",authToken.token);
        prefs.putString("net.example.authSecret",authToken.secret);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve the stored tokens to build a new `TwitterSession` if they exist?

Comment: Better you have to ask for official support https://twittercommunity.com/search?q=create%20twitter%20session%20from%20access%20token

Comment: Last time I tried, I did *not* get help there. I presume some StackOverflowers have written Twitter Android apps though ...

Comment: An IOS attempt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811276/how-do-i-store-access-a-twitter-fabric-login-session-ios-swift

Comment: That's e-mail-based. :-/

Comment: I think you have to serialize and store the twitter session for re-use..https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/blob/master/twitter-core/src/test/java/com/twitter/sdk/android/core/PreferenceStoreStrategyTest.java . go through the project deeply you will get some idea..