# Fabric: TwitterSession always null

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I want to check if the user is already connected on Twitter in order to post tweets from my android application. Using Fabric, I check the `TwitterSession` via this code:

```
TwitterCore twitterCore = TwitterCore.getInstance();
TwitterSession twitterSession = twitterCore.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
return (twitterSession != null && !twitterSession.getAuthToken().isExpired());
```

The problem is that the `twitterSession` is always null, even if I'm connected on the Twitter application.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize it in onCreate firstly. I was used twitter digits and it initilize somthing like that :

```
 TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
        Fabric.with(this, new Answers(), new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits());
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .build());

        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .build());

        final Digits digits = new Digits.Builder()
                .withDigitsEventLogger(new AnswersLogger())
                .build();
```

i think look at [this page](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/overview.html)

Comment: Have I to initialize the twitterSession or the twitterCore on the onCreate?

Comment: How can I do that? Because I'm using this function on a simple class and not on an Activity.

Comment: you have to initilize it in your base activity or your login activity than it gives you active sesion. please look at this web site. They give sample code